# Google Sheets Links between sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google, links

I have two sheets in one google sheets document. One is a project log with project details and the other is a customer list. I have linked the customer cell to the cell with their project. When I add new customers the cells change but link stays to the same cell. Is there a way to get the link to change cells with the customer location without having to relink?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to create a [named range](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175) for each customer. Then **Insert > Link** that points to that named range.

Alternatively, use the name box in the upper left-hand corner of the spreadsheet window, right next to the formula bar, to quickly jump to a named range. You can open the name box by pressing **Control+J**.